# angular $element.focus vs jquery $(selector).focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a directive called keepFocus which is called but the `$element.focus` part is not creating the focus.

```
.directive("keepFocus", ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    /*
    Intended use:
        <input keep-focus ng-model='someModel.value'></input>
    */
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, attrs, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                // $timeout(function () {
                //     $element[0].focus();
                // },500);
                //setTimeout(function() { $element[0].focus() }, 3000);

                //this works
                setTimeout(function() { $('.cart-item-quantity input')[0].focus() }, 3000);
                return value;
            });

        }
    };
}])
```

What I have tested so far:

- normal jQuery is available
- `$('.cart-item-quantity input') == $element //false`
- `$('.cart-item-quantity input')[0] == $element[0] //false`

The last result surprised me as the elements looked identical until I looked closer and saw that `$element[0]` has got `ng-valid ng-dirty` class while the jQuery version has the `ng-pristine ng-valid` class

I've never worked with angular before (am working on someone else's project) so not sure where to go from here.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

---

UPDATE

---

Found the culprit, just need to figure out how to get around it now!

```
$scope.update = function (skuid, quantity) {
        quantity = sanitizeQuantity(quantity);

        $http
            .post(shoppingCartServiceUrl + '/UpdateQuantity', { skuid: skuid, quantity: quantity })
            .then(function (response) {
                //$scope.cart = response.data.d; -- this is the issue
                console.log(response.data.d);
                $scope.calculateTotalWithDonation();
            });
    };
```

Comment: For me everything works: http://plnkr.co/edit/IYNKBZGj93ghuKSPkmzH?p=preview

Comment: @MaximShoustin hmmm, must be something else taking the focus so. thanks very much!

Comment: @MaximShoustin I upgraded my version of angular and used `track by $index` that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer as an issue on Angular's [Github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13327). The answer was to use tracking (you need v1.3 + for this).

```
<div class="cart-items" ng-repeat="item in cart.Items track by $index">
        <div class="cart-item">
            <div class="cart-item-quantity">
                <input keep-focus type="text" maxlength="3" ng-model="cart.Items[$index].Quantity" ng-change="update(cart.Items[$index].SKUID, cart.Items[$index].Quantity)" ng-blur="update(cart.Items[$index].SKUID, cart.Items[$index].Quantity)"/>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```